# How to get requested attribute in WSO2 identity server through rest api

Tags: rest, wso2, query-string

How can i get requested attribute for all the user in WSO2 identity server through Rest API.

I am trying hit below endpoint with below query parameter but it is not woking with WSO2 identity server.

https://:9443/wso2/scim/Users?attributes=active

Can any one help me to get only requested parameters from users.

Answer (score 0):

Current SCIM implementation does not support for these query parameters. Please refer [Jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4952).